# HTML bootstrap content structure

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am putting my content to HTML(Bootstrap4) but then i started styling CSS I realized my HTML structure is pretty bad. I added the main border around content to the "container" class, so then i realized the h titles are inside, but i need outside like in my picture with example. And this structure have much more problems.
What HTML structure would be the best and cleanest for my content like in my example picture. Maybe i just need to use simple HTML tables for this?

My expected result:

[image]

```css
#work-process {
    padding: 78px 0 150px 0;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;      
    line-height: normal;
    color: #424242;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #e9e9e9;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.col-lg-3 {
    padding-left: 54px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.col-lg-3:not(:last-child):after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px; 
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2; 
}

.col-lg-3:not(:last-child):before {
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid #e9e9e9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px; 
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <section id="work-process">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <h2>1. KONSULTACIJA</h2>
                    <p>Aptarsime situaciją ir įvertinsime preliminarią kainą</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <h2>2. PROJEKTAVIMAS</h2>
                    <p>2.1. Paruošiami brėžiniai ir kelios baldų vizualizacijos.
                        2.2. Užsakovo vizualizacijų pastabų ar pageidavimų korekcijos</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <h2>3. GAMYBA</h2>
                    <p>Pagaminsime baldūs</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <h2>4. PRISTATYMAS / MONTAVIMAS</h2>
                    <p>Pristatysime ir sumontuosime nestandartinius baldūs</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    Susisiekite 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    Esant poreikiuj sukursime užsakymą pagal užsakovo.. 
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    Daugiau informacijos 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Full example with css: https://jsfiddle.net/L3wzet5g/

Comment: In theory your HTML layout is perfectly fine; it adheres to Bootstrap's rules, and seems an adequate way of going about the problem. Was there a particular part of it that you were struggling with?

Comment: Yes it's good by Bootstrap rules, but i can't get what i need, like i said before the main problem is border, now my bold titles is inside, but i need outside the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex boxes wouldn't cut it, so we can use `position:absolute` to get this done... for this, had to add extra divs so that we can control the positioning more precisely...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<section id="work-process">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row styledContainer">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class='headingContainer'>
          <div class='headingBox'>
            <h2>1. KONSULTACIJA</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>Aptarsime situaciją ir įvertinsime preliminarią kainą</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class='headingContainer'>
          <div class='headingBox'>
            <h2>2. PROJEKTAVIMAS</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>2.1. Paruošiami brėžiniai ir kelios baldų vizualizacijos. 2.2. Užsakovo vizualizacijų pastabų ar pageidavimų korekcijos</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class='headingContainer'>
          <div class='headingBox'>
            <h2>3. GAMYBA</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>Pagaminsime baldūs</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class='headingContainer'>
          <div class='headingBox'>
            <h2>4. PRISTATYMAS / MONTAVIMAS</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>Pristatysime ir sumontuosime nestandartinius baldūs</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bottomRow">
      <div class="col-lg-3 separateBorder">
        <p>Susisiekite</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>Esant poreikiuj sukursime užsakymą pagal užsakovo..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>Daugiau informacijos</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<style>
  #work-process {
    padding: 78px 0 150px 0;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #424242;
  }
  
  .container {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .col-lg-3 {
    padding-left: 54px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  .styledContainer .col-lg-3:not(:last-child):after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .styledContainer .col-lg-3:not(:last-child):before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid #e9e9e9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .styledContainer .col-lg-3 {
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .styledContainer .col-lg-3 p,
  .styledContainer .col-lg-6 p {
    padding-left: 54px;
  }
  
  #work-process>.container>.styledContainer {
    border-top: 20px solid #fbfbfb;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  
  .styledContainer .headingBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
  }
  
  .separateBorder {
    border-right: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
  }
  
  @media screen AND (max-width:991px) {
    .styledContainer .headingBox {
      top: auto;
    }
    .styledContainer .headingContainer {
      background-color: #fbfbfb;
    }
    .styledContainer .headingContainer {
      height: 20px;
    }
    .separateBorder {
      border-right: none;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen AND (min-width:1200px) {
    #work-process>.container>.styledContainer {
      border-top: 20px solid #fbfbfb;
      padding-top: 42px;
    }
    .styledContainer .headingBox {
      position: absolute;
      top: -65px;
    }
  }
  
  .bottomRow {
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was almost what I needed. I just need to do some changes in my mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.
Try this code. It'll help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h4>1:I'm Demo</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h4>2:I'm Demo 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h4>3:I'm Demo 3</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row second_row">
        <div class="col">
          <p>1:I'm paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>2:I'm paragraph 2</p>
            <p>2:I'm paragraph 2</p>
            <p>2:I'm paragraph 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>3:I'm paragraph 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row third_row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <p>1:I'm on third line</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <p>2:I'm  on third line lorem ipsum dorem 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Css Code:

```
.second_row{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Title</title>
<style>
#work-process {
    padding: 78px 0 150px 0;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;      
    line-height: normal;
    color: #424242;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #e9e9e9;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.col-lg-3 {
    padding-left: 54px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.col-lg-3:not(:last-child):after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px; 
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2; 
}

.col-lg-3:not(:last-child):before {
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 40px solid #e9e9e9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px; 
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1; 
}
.vl {
border-left: 2px solid grey ;
  height:30px ;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>





    <section id="work-process">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: 65px; "><h2>1. KONSULTACIJA</h2></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><h2>2. PROJEKTAVIMAS</h2></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><h2>3. GAMYBA</h2></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 "  style="margin-left: -100px;"><h2>4. PRISTATYMAS / MONTAVIMAS</h2></div>
                </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">

                    <p>Aptarsime situaciją ir įvertinsime preliminarią kainą</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">

                    <p>2.1. Paruošiami brėžiniai ir kelios baldų vizualizacijos.
                        2.2. Užsakovo vizualizacijų pastabų ar pageidavimų korekcijos</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">

                    <p>Pagaminsime baldūs</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">

                    <p>Pristatysime ir sumontuosime nestandartinius baldūs</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="line-height: 200%;">    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 text-center" > 
                          <u style="c   olor: red; padding-top: 100px;"><m style="color: black;">Susisiekite</m> </u> <img src="123.jpg">                         

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"><div class="vl"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    Esant poreikiuj sukursime užsakymą pagal užsakovo Daugiau informacijos 
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>


    <div class="vl"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]